# strange characters in debug file

Tags: debug

recently I get a weird log in WordPress debug file

```
[09-Dec-2021 20:26:57 UTC] 03AGdBq27pjsLRdeIVXfN_q2XMOOFf1OY3rFj5GIEfJHVBrzTHplTE0-zMSneSJVhmFP_jRq37J59JWGUYLOUKt3zv8PLs0c8eU7Gb6xaIO_7DZpFVMVkJoK7_BkaW1rxG8bl03zMKeBkrkHIt0115t9QQmI_vO3Y3l1pvpF58P1GEtQase2IX7BUCd-gx4BiMNsNvZ5ImHcPQUuJKeqpXQffMi2cjPI_-YBYABv1U6GTEEAN8ZIoPZmpNPnXxbuI0IWBRFlCOB91G38MwrW3Fq5GN6sRtHR26IW0Tv-7gGCYHZKyVnwbhI9DI7ibMp80GBiadKIF-X2NLSmfvQZR5foXXF6PzJBI_RZL666kr0OHROY0hM7v2mMQReCaR00pRLbQhBSSC0abNF2EEvC4fftxqfu3582Gfgff3WWtwW7KcZaV1sPumTX5deBsI1hr1YzuvIWMweWAUbxMnfbI2ijDZ1H9DzENDja5vRZrqubWmUx4K5QCrDzk
```

do you have any idea where is it come from?!

Comment: I got it. when I use ESI in litespeed-cache, when the block catch nothing, it got this error

Comment: Have you scanned for malware?